# Can I connect this router directly to the serial port of my pc to try to unbrick?

Tags: serial

Good day, please forgive me if I'm asking an obvious or otherwise ridiculous question. I am a programmer and I have little experience with electronics . I have a cisco Linksys WRT54G2 V1 router that is bricked. I also have a pc with a serial port on it. From googling there seems to be a serial access on the board of the router, but no tutorials on how to set it up. Most people use a TTL USB adapter, which I do not have. So I'm wondering if I can use my serial port on my pc directly. If so how, which pins would correspond to which pins.

I've inserted a picture that I found online that illustrates what I'm asking. I.e. can i just connect pins 1-5 (in the picture below) to pins 1-5 of my pc serial port and run one of the debrick utilities?  Any info at all would be helpful. Again, I do apologize if I'm asking nonsense.

[image]

Comment: I assume, you tried a Power on Reset, and contacted Linksys tech support

Comment: https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Linksys_WRT54GS_v5.0_&_5.1_&_6.0

Comment: The close reason is incorrect. I voted to close this because *repair* questions must show an understanding of what is being repaired.

Answer (score 4):

NO you can't connect the serial port (COM) of a PC, to the UART on the router's PCB. The COM port is using high voltage levels (12-15V), and the router's UART is using low voltages (probably 3.3V or 5V). If you'll connect the COM to the router, you could possibly harm your device.

Comment: PCs do not necessarily use +/- 12V and certainly they don't even have +/- 15V.

Answer (score 3):

No, the on-board serial port will be both **inverted** and at 0/5V (or maybe 0/3.3V) **"TTL" levels**. So connecting it to +/-10V-ish RS-232 levels won't work and could damage the router (it should not damage the RS-232 drivers since they are supposed to be very robust)

A chip such as a [MAX232](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/max232.pdf) can be used to convert the levels (and invert), however you'd be far better off to just purchase an inexpensive USB<->TTL converter based on chips such as FTDI CP2102 or CH340. You can get them for very low prices from China, or places such as Amazon (I can get same day delivery to my door, maybe you can too).

Get the kind with individual flying female leads and *carefully* match them up with the mating pins one at a time, paying particular care to GND and power, or the module could be instantly and permanently fried, conceivably damaging your computer too with the USB connection.

Answer (score 1):

The RS-232C voltage levels for logic 0 and logic 1 from the PC COM port are +12 V and -12 V.

Your router expects 3.3 V and 0 V or possibly 5 V and 0 V. Either way, the RS-232C levels will damage it permanently.

Making a voltage translator is probably more expensive than buying a USB-to-LVTTL adaptor cable. That will give your PC another COM: port with 3.3 V and 0 V levels on the end of the cable. They can be bought in the UK from Amazon or wherever for a few pounds. You mention such a cable and it'll be the most reliable way. It's a few days delay but it the long run, an unbroken router is worth much more than the wait and the cable.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't connect the PC directly, as it uses RS-232 voltage levels, and the device uses 5V or 3.3V logic voltage levels, so wrong voltage levels.

The pins will also likey not match so connecting pins by number is also likely wrong.